# Cakephp 2.x and Jquery Ajax - Cake doesn't think request is ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I am working on a little cakePHP application and am trying to AJAX it up a bit with JQuery to make it work a bit nicer for users.

I have just followed this tutorial: [Cakephp Jquery AJAX Tutorial](http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/ajax_delete_with_cakephp_and_jquery) but for some reason it isn't working.

One great bit about the tutorial is that functionality falls back to normal CakePHP if the request isn't an AJAX request so my app still works but it doesn't work the AJAX way...

It looks like in my Controller, the request doesn't pass the test:

```
if($this->request->is('ajax'))
```

and so continues onto the normal `$this->redirect(...)` of the non-AJAX way.

Could it be something to do with the if statement for 'ajax'? In the tutorial the author is using a version of cakePHP before 2.0 and so uses `$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()` but this was deprecated as of cakePHP 2.0.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Okay I've managed to get it working if I don't use the cakePHP helper function: $this->Html->link() but just write an <a> element myself without the href to: 'action'=>'delete' but this means it won't work for people who have javascript disabled, the whole point of the tutorial is that it will work either way based on if request->is('ajax')...

It looks like the non-ajax call is getting priority over the ajax call and so the if statement is never hit...or something.

Comment: Update: Okay, I now have the HtmlHelper link() function back in and I call preventDefault() in the jquery click handler and now it works!! I'm assuming that if someone has Js disabled then the jQuery wouldn't get touched and therefore 'default' (going to the link) won't be prevented and my cakephp will still work for them. Is this true?

Answer (score 0):

[JsHelper::link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#other-methods) might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As I think you have discovered, it's nothing to do with Cake.  It's because in the tutorial he tells you to make a link, then you are clicking the link to run the action.  This causes the AJAX request to fire, but also the actual link gets followed.

You need `preventDefault()` in your jQuery click event, to stop the browser from following the link in the normal way. This will not affect the link if the user doesn't have JavaScript... because they won't have the click event occur in the first place :)